# Render component when reaching bottom of div

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I've written a component that renders a bunch of data from an API in a grid. The full array is ~2,000 in length and is saved in context API, but I only want to render the elements that the user is looking at. So I start with `48` and add another 48 whenever the user gets to the bottom of the page. The `console.log()` on line `16` always fires at the bottom, as expected, but for some reason the state is not updating. Can someone point out to me why this is the case? Thanks

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import '../styles/Home.module.css'
import DAO from '../components/DAO'
import { DaosContext } from "../context/daos"

const DAO_SCROLL_GROUPS = 48

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const { daos } = useContext(DaosContext);
  const [daosToRender, setDaosToRender] = useState<number>(DAO_SCROLL_GROUPS)

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const bottom = Math.ceil(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight
    if (bottom) {
      const newDaoNumber = daosToRender + DAO_SCROLL_GROUPS
      console.log("At the bottom", daosToRender, newDaoNumber)
      setDaosToRender(newDaoNumber)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, {
    })

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }
  }, [])

  const daoList = daos.splice(0, daosToRender)
  
  return (
    <div className="bg-gradient-to-br from-black to-purple via-black h-100vh flex flex-col justify-between">
      <div className={'flex text-white text-md px-8 mt-4'}>
        <div>DAOs: {daos.length}</div>
      </div>
      <div className="grid xl:grid-cols-6 md:grid-cols-4 gap-4 mt-4 p-8">
        {daoList.map((dao) => {
          return (
            dao && <DAO key={dao.id} space={dao} />
          )}
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: You may want to check this out: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering based on `daoList`. Put this in a state and update each time `daosToRender` is updated.

Example

```
const [daoList, setDaoList] = useState([]);
```

Use `useEffect` to update `daoList` with dependency array `daosToRender`

```
useEffect(()=>{
   setDaoList(daos.splice(0, daosToRender))
}, [daosToRender, daos]);
```